# Toggle parent class (add/remove) of radio button

Tags: javascript

I have this working with checkboxes like so:

```
    window.onload=function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          this.parentNode.classList.add('border-blue');
        } else {
          this.parentNode.classList.remove('border-blue');
        }
      })
    })
   }
```

However, when I change the `type="radio"`, the `class` isn't removed. How do I do this with radio buttons?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="dfield">
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="border-blue">
      <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="field  group  required valid" value="0.8" vt="0.8" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Small Car</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="border-blue">
      <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="field  group  required valid" value="1" vt="1" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Medium Car</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        this.parentNode.classList.add('border-blue');
      } else {
        this.parentNode.classList.remove('border-blue');
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="dfield">
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="border-blue">
          <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="field  group  required valid" value="0.8" vt="0.8" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Small Car</span>
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="border-blue">
          <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="field  group  required valid" value="1" vt="1" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Medium Car</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not applying or removing classes from the checkboxes. You are doing it to its parent components. Can you show us your HTML structure?

Comment: I've amended the question to show the HTML

Comment: It's because radios don't fire an event when they are unchecked so your change event should loop through all the radios and then remove class from all unchecked parents then re-add it to the one that is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for a checkbox but use a radio button.

You also need to toggle them off in siblings perhaps.

Note: you have a starting point with all of them blue-border so it does not do that until one is changed (you have a change event).  You could either have removed the class in the original markup or trigger a change event during page load on one of them (without changing the value)

I made no assumptions on your usage or need but simply illustrate the issue and one possible solution.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
    .forEach(function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('change', function() {
        // this is a high handed approach, you may need to walk the parent node siblings children instead.
        // turn off what is on
        var bb = document.getElementsByClassName("border-blue");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < bb.length; i++) {
          bb[i].classList.remove('border-blue');
        }

        if (this.checked) {
          this.parentNode.classList.add('border-blue');
        } else {
          this.parentNode.classList.remove('border-blue');
        }
      })
    })
}
```

```css
.label-wrapper {
  border: solid lime 3px;
}

.border-blue {
  border: solid blue 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dfield">
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="label-wrapper border-blue">
          <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb0" class="field  group  required valid" value="0.8" vt="0.8" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Small Car</span>
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_column">
    <label for="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="label-wrapper border-blue">
          <input name="fieldname77_1" id="fieldname77_1_rb1" class="field  group  required valid" value="1" vt="1" type="radio" aria-invalid="false"> <span>Medium Car</span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi kindly try my code:

```
var radioBtn = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

window.onload = function() {
  radioBtn.forEach(function(currentNode) {
    currentNode.addEventListener('change', function() {
      // removing class to all nodes
      radioBtn.forEach(function(node) {
        node.parentElement.classList.remove('border-blue');
      });
      // then add the class on the specified node
      currentNode.parentElement.classList.add('border-blue');
    });
  });
};
```

My suggestion is remove the class to all of the related elements, then lastly add the class again to that specified element.

Hope this will help or will give a new and better Idea.